# Is there a way in c++ to represent pSomePointer->pValue->nSubvalue using dot operators instead of ->

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that in c++

```
pSomePointer->pValue = (*pSomePointer).pValue
```

how can i represent the following case in the above mentioned form:

```
pSomePointer->pValue->nSubvalue
```

I know that we use pSomePointer->pValue->nSubvalue in our codes, but I am just curious if there is any way of doing this in c++.

what I had tried and got errors are:

```
(*pSomePointer).(*pValue) ).nSubvalue;

(*pSomePointer.pValue).nSubvalue;
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why would you want to avoid `pSomePointer->value->subvalue`? It's a syntactic sugar given to us so we don't have to do it like you tried to do.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen , thanks for replying, there is no actual problem that i want to solve like this. I just want to check if can be done in nested pointers or so.

Comment: `(*((*pSomePointer).value)).subvalue` - why on earth anyone would do this I haven't a clue, but yes, you can.

Comment: @WhozCraig ,thank you. I think of one example where we use ++ in a loop for getting next memory locations , one example could be this statement in a loop { (*((*pSomePointer++).value)).subvalue = (*((*pSomeOtherPointer++).value)).subvalue; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you're really missing is that `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `*` and that the right-hand side of `->` and `.` is a simple identifier, not a general expression.

With that, we get

```
foo->bar->baz
```

is equivalent to

```
(foo->bar)->baz
```

is equivalent to

```
((*foo).bar)->baz
```

is equivalent to

```
(*((*foo).bar)).baz
```

is equivalent to

```
(*(*foo).bar).baz
```

(after removing a redundant pair of parens).

---

Your attempts don't work because `.(` is a syntax error and `*pSomePointer.value` parses as `*(pSomePointer.value)` (and you can't use `.` on a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. Let me split it into steps:

We have a pointer `pSomePointer`. Now, we want to get the actual object (pointee):

```
*pSomePointer
```

Now, we want to get the member `value` from this object:

```
(*pSomePointer).value
```

Now we need to dereference our expression to get an object pointed to by `value`

```
*((*pSomePointer).value)
```

And now we can access `subvalue` of our object:

```
(*((*pSomePointer).value)).subvalue
```

[See it online!](http://cpp.sh/9yhgi)

---

This being said, I strongly discourage from ever using this notation. It's terribly hard to read and very error prone (although those errors would be compiler errors mostly).
Operator `->` was creater for programmers convenice, and praise the commitees for that.

Comment: perfect my friend, now it makes sense